# Convert SQL Server 2008's .MDF to SQL Server 2005's?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a `.MDF` file which is of SQL Server 2008.

But I don't have SQL Server 2008 I only have SQL Server 2005.

Now I am required to attach that `.MDF` to my SQL Server 2005 instance.

Is there any way to do this?

I don't want to use SQL Server 2008.

Is there any way to convert `.MDF` to lower version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any way. You will need to attach it to a 2008 instance then export the data.

Comment: ok thanks for answering..but may is there any online facility which providing this kind of .MDF conversions?

Comment: @Pritesh - Not as far as I'm aware. Can't you just download SQL Server 2008 Express?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of.  You can be the first to make it, though.  I doubt you'll have many customers.

Comment: Ha ha ha...ok i will installing it..but i will not dare to make online facility to make converting .MDF files :)

Answer (score 2):

Read the following article [**How to Downgrade SQL Server Database from a higher version to a lower version**](http://www.myTechMantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Downgrade_SQL_Server_Database_P1.html) which has an example to downgrade a SQL Server database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2008 Using SQL Server Integration Services.

I would also recommend you to read [**Why an SQL Server Database from a higher version cannot be restored onto a lower version of SQL Server?**](http://www.myTechMantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Unable_to_Restore_Database_From_Backup.html) to know why you can’t restore a SQL Server Database from higher version of SQL Server to lower version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach your database to some SQL 2008 instance and script database with some tool (for example using standard tool from management studio) and after that apply generated scripts to SQL 2005 instance.